# Некорректное отображение темы письма

Tags: email, php, кодировка

Всем, привет! Уважаемое сообщество, прошу вашей помощи, вопрос заключается в следующем: Есть контактная форма, после ее заполнения и подтверждения происходит отправка письма администратору сайта. Проблема заключается в том, что при отображении общего списка всех сообщений пришедших с почтового сервера откуда происходит отправка, тема письма отображается корректно, но как только пытаюсь просмотреть письмо, то заголовок сразу превращается в вопросики. Все остальное отображается корректно. Пробовал менять кодировку заголовка письма, не помогает, пробовал менять кодировку страницы, тоже не помогает, в общем поэтому и обращаюсь. Если нужны куски кода я приложу, скажите только, что конкретно. Заранее благодарен!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

Comment: @inso забыл совсем про эту библиотеку )

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте кодировать заголовок в BASE64
например, если используется функция mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) и все написано в кодировке utf-8, то заголовок будет примерно такой:

```
$subject = '=?utf-8?B?'. base64_encode('Текст заголовка') .'?=';
```

Подробнее об этом можно почитать хотя бы [здесь](http://webew.ru/articles/297.webew)

Простой пример скрипта (!в кодировке utf-8):

```
$to = 'Ваш имейл';
$subject = '=?utf-8?B?'. base64_encode('Текст заголовка') .'?=';
$message = 'Тест';

$headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From:Имейл сервера\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: @mkblade после использования функции `base64_encode()` в тему письма попадает вот что `z/Du4uXw6uA=` но хочу сказать, как вы правильно заметили да я и использую функцию mail()

Comment: добавил простой пример отправки письма, проверил, у меня работает.. кодировка файла php -- utf8

Comment: @mkblade спасибо за советы, воспользовался  библиотекой `PHPMailer`